# Customizer, change preview url when a control changes

Tags: theme-customizer, api

I've a dropdown control that lists all pages of the website.

When I select a page in the dropdown I would update the preview iframe to that page.

There is the following method to change the customizer `previewUrl`

`wp.customize.previewer.previewUrl( url )`

But I can't realize how and where exactly I should do this.
The dropdown control has transport set to `refresh` and the preview will refresh automatically everytime the control value changes.

Maybe a solution could be to change the `previewUrl` before the customizer automatically refresh the preview.

Do you have any suggestions to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gonna have a go... say you have a theme option `themeoption[id]`... instead of setting transport `refresh`, set it to `postMessage` instead, and then add this code to create a callback that first gets the page URL via AJAX then sends that back to the `previewUrl` as you mentioned before refreshing...

```
add_action('customize_preview_init,'preview_override_loader');
function preview_override_loader() {
    add_action('wp_footer','preview_override_script');
    function preview_override_script() {
        $adminajax = admin_url('admin-ajax.php');
        echo "wp.customize('themeoption[id]',function(value) {
            value.bind(function(to) {
                console.log('Posted ID: '+to); /* debug point */
                jQuery.get({url:'".$adminajax.php"', 
                    {action:'get_preview_permalink',postid:to}, 
                    function(data) {
                        if (data) {
                            console.log('Permalink: '+data); /* debug point */
                            wp.customize.previewer.previewUrl(data);
                            wp.customize.previewer.refresh();
                        }
                    } 
                });
            });
        });"
    }
}
```

Then just add a small AJAX function to return the permalink... this is somewhat assuming that the dropdown control is saving/posting a single numeric post ID.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_get_preview_permalink','get_preview_permalink');
function get_preview_permalink() {
    $postid = $_GET['postid'];
    echo get_permalink($postid);
    exit;
}
```

Untested crazy workaround but it seems like it might do the trick..?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one when you plan to change the current URL from controls panel: 
`wp.customize.previewer.previewUrl( url )`

or try this one while you intend to change the URL from preview frame:
`wp.customize.preview.send( "url", url )`

---

Moreover, here is how to get the current preview URL from the controls panel:
`wp.customize.previewer.previewUrl()`